# Как в nextjs сделать api?

Tags: nextjs

На сайте у меня имеется форма поиска, после нажатия кнопки я хочу отправить GET запрос на url и получить json, но наверное я бы хотел этот json разбить на функции, чтобы получать title, text и тд. Как правильнее это сделать? Нужно в папке api все создавать? Ничего не понимаю))

Прошу не кидать ссылки на документацию, я только оттуда. Хочется глянуть на какие-то примеры ваши, как вы это делали)